# From vector to heatmap in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

My data looks like this:

```
A = [1 1 0;
     1 2 1;
     2 2 0;
     2 1 1]
```

The first two columns represent interactions. The third one represents the presents or absence of the interaction. How can I transform this into a heat map like this:

```
  1 2
1 0 1
2 1 0
```

I used find, but is there a faster and more elegant way to do it?

Comment: How are you getting from `A` to your heat map?

Comment: This is exactly my question. How can I transform A into the following interaction matrix.

Comment: Okay, then what is the criteria you're using?

Comment: Are you guaranteed to always have *exactly* one row in `A` for each element in the heat map?

Comment: See if `full(spconvert(A))` is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Is it simple enough?

```
n = max(A(:, 1));
m = max(A(:, 2));
b = nan(n, m);
for i = 1:length(A)
    b(A(i, 1), A(i, 2)) = A(i, 3);
end
```

I've tried some other code, but it **failed**. Thus the above might be the simpliest:

```
n = max(A(:, 1));
m = max(A(:, 2));
b = nan(n, m);
b(A(:, 1), A(:, 2)) = A(:, 3);
```

Anyway, I'd like to how you implement using `find`